# Symfony3 Swiftmailer Not Sending Email in production

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

When I test my code on the local server, emails are being sent. However, when I deploy it on my actual server, emails are not being sent. I have deactivated the 'secure apps' from Google. How can I send the emails ?
By the way, whenever I delete the spool option is get a 500 Internal Server Error. I do not need spool but can't seem to be able to get rid of it.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my controller

```
    public function contactAction(Request $request) {
       $enquiry = new Enquiry();
       $form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $enquiry); 
       $form->handleRequest($request);

      if($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
        // Send email
        $name = $form["name"]->getData();
        $email = $form["email"]->getData(); 
        $subject = $form["subject"]->getData();  
        $body = $form["body"]->getData();                  
         // Send message
         $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject($subject)
                    ->setFrom($email)
                    ->setTo('myEmail@gmail.com')
                    ->setBody($this->renderView('Emails/emailTemp.html.twig', array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'subject' => $subject,
                        'body' => $body,

                        )
                    ))

        ;

                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
                $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    'Email has been sent!'
                );
                return $this->redirectToRoute('contactme');            


    }
```

config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: myemail@gmail.com
mailer_password: MyPasWd
```

Comment: What are the main differences between the local server and the actual server?

Comment: Actual server is a shared hosting plan at  hostgator

Comment: That doesn't help! I'm wondering if the SSL port it being blocked? Have you tried with just: transport, username, password     only?

Comment: It is not being blocked. I have contacted hostgator about it. And yes, I have tried it with only the password, username, and transport and still did not work

Comment: Are you using 2-Step-Verification for this Gmail account? If yes you would need to follow this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833.